# Python socket programming with multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to use sockets in python. For now, I'm trying to get it such that if any client sends any message it is received at all clients. However I'm getting very weird results. I think it's because I'm using multiple threads. The output of the program changes every time I run it. Is this a threading problem or is it something else?

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *
from server import Server
from client import Client

s = Server()
start_new_thread(s.acceptConnection,())


m = Client("m")
k = Client("k")
start_new_thread(m.recieveData,())
start_new_thread(k.recieveData,())
k.sendData("Hey!")
print "*"*100
print repr(k.data()), repr(m.data())
print "*"*100
m.sendData("okay okay")
print "*"*100
print repr(k.data()), repr(m.data())
print "*"*100
m.client.close()
k.client.close()
s.s.close()
```

Server Class:

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self,port = 5555):
        self.host = 'localhost'  # '' means connect to all hosts
        self.port = port
        self.text = ""        
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        try:
            self.s.bind((self.host, self.port))
        except socket.error as e:
            print(str(e))
        self.s.listen(2)
        print "Waiting for a connection.\n"
        self.connections = []

    def threaded_client(self,conn):
        # conn.send("Connected to server\n")
        while True:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(2048)
            except:
                data = ""
            if(not data):
                break
            # conn.sendall(reply)
            for c,a in self.connections:
                try:
                    c.sendall(data + "\n")
                except:
                    print "connection lost\n"
                    self.connections.remove((c,a))
        conn.close()

    def acceptConnection(self):
        while True:
            conn, addr = self.s.accept()
            self.connections += [(conn,addr)]
            start_new_thread(self.threaded_client,(conn,))
```

Client class:

```
import socket
import sys
from thread import *

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.port = 5555
        self.name = name
        self.client= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
        self.client.connect((self.host,self.port))
        self.text = ""

    def sendData(self,data):
        self.client.send(data)

    def recieveData(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.client.recv(2048)
            except:
                break
            if data:
                self.text = data
        self.client.close()

    def data(self):
        return self.text

    def closeClient(self):
        self.client.close()
```

Comment: what do you mean the output changes ?

Comment: The output every time I run the program is different than the last time

Comment: in what way ? Different ordering, corrupted ?

Comment: Well the difference is in the output of the print statements in the main program where I print the data stored in clients. Sometimes all of them happen to be empty strings. Sometimes some of them are "Hey!\n" or sometimes some of the are "okay okay\n". Ideally the output should be two "Hey!"'s followed by two "okay okay"'s as that is the order in which I send the data to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway you have no warrants about the data was already come back to the clients when you try to print it. You should introduce some `Conditions` and use `wait()` and `notifyAll()` to make sure the data was arrive.... To check if my guess is correct put some `sleep()` in your test:

```
import time
k.sendData("Hey!")
print "*"*100
time.sleep(200)
print repr(k.data()), repr(m.data())
print "*"*100
m.sendData("okay okay")
print "*"*100
time.sleep(200)
print repr(k.data()), repr(m.data())
print "*"*100
```

If it works you should use conditions and notify to do your tests.

Moreover you must protect `data` access by a `Lock()`.

```
def recieveData(self):

    while True:
        try:
            data = self.client.recv(2048)
        except:
            break
        if data:
            self.l.acquire()
            self.text = data
            self.l.release()
    self.client.close()

def data(self):
    self.l.acquire()
    ret = self.text
    self.l.release()
    return ret
```

Where attribute `l` of clients are defined in `__init__` by

```
self.l=threading.Lock()
```

Comment: The sleep idea works! If I sleep for one second after sending the data, I get the required results. Thanks! I have one more question on this -- in my server and client class am I closing my server and client sockets properly?

Comment: @meh123 close is good but add shutdown is better. I must go to sleep :)